# Modeling many different Classes in objc pattern

Tags: ios, design-patterns, model

Imagine you have 300 different kind of units. Each unit has different special abilities. For example unit18 gets invisible if it stands near to a tree. Unit33 and unit212 has the same ability. How can I model these 300 unique units in a clever way?

I only have two ideas which both sucks. Either create one class for each unit and end up with 300 classes. And every time I have to check there will such construct:

```
for (Unit *unit in units)
{
    if ([unit isKindOfClass:[Unit1 class]])
    {
      // do something
    }
    else if ([unit isKindOfClass:[Unit2 class]])
    {
      // do something
    }
    else if ([unit isKindOfClass:[Unitxxx class]])
    {
      // do something
    }
}
```

The other solution is creating a monolith monster unit class which has all abilities.

I thought of a design like explained in this post:
http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2010/06/prefer-composition-inheritance/

I already tried to make this kind of design but it did not work out. 
[image]

I appreciate every suggestion.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should load all of your objects into an array, this helps make more dynamic and efficient code.

Comment: So you recommend creating 300 different classes. One for each unit?

Comment: I think this kind of question is better suited for gamedev.SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ray Wenderlich just posted an new Blogpost about a component based architecture. This is exactly what I was looking for.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/24878/introduction-to-component-based-architecture-in-games

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html). Unit18, Unit33 and Unit212 could all conform to the TreeInvisibility protocol.

To check is a unit conforms to a protocol, you call `[unit conformsToProtocol:@protocol(TreeInvisibility)]`.

The nice thing here is that classes can inherit from multiple Protocols. This allows you to mix and match combinations of protocols.

---

Now that I think about it more, you would still have to write 300 classes using this method, in addition to all the protocols. This just makes controlling the units easier because you only need to check the different protocols not for the individual classes.

It may not be the best solution for you, but hopefully it will help point you in a good direction.